# Converting RGB value into ColorMatrix

Tags: c#, vb.net, math, system.drawing, colormatrix

I would like to colorize a black-white image.

To do that, I use a ColorMatrix.
For example, when I want to color the image red, I use this ColorMatrix:

```
1,0,0,0,0,
0,1,0,0,0,
0,0,1,0,0,
0,0,0,1,0,
1,0,0,0,0,
```

Now I would like to choose a color from a color chart, for example from such a color chart:

[image]

My plan was to use GetPixel to retrieve the color under the cursor and convert this RGB value to a ColorMatrix.

When I would use GetPixel over the color Red, I would get

```
R: 255
G: 0
B: 0
```

How could I turn the Red value of 255 into a ColorMatrix value?
It would be 1.0.
If the Red value was 127, the value would be 0.5

Should I simply use a "rule of three" to determine the value of 1.0, or how should this be handled?

Answer (score 5):

Firstly, I think you should read up on the [`ColorMatrix`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.imaging.colormatrix%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) class, and perhaps refresh your understanding of matrices (although the `ColorMatrix` documentation gives you enough information that you don't need to understand the matrix maths).

Let's look at your matrix:

```
1,0,0,0,0
0,1,0,0,0
0,0,1,0,0
0,0,0,1,0
1,0,0,0,0
```

This matrix will scale the red, green, blue, and alpha components by 1, and then add 1 to the red component, and 0 to the green, blue, and alpha components.

I don't think this is really what you want. To colorise an image I think it would be better to multiply your image RGB values instead of adding to them. Otherwise, if you had a black and white image with a pixel that was white (i.e. RGB 1, 1, 1) then when you tried to colour it, it would remain white, when it should really take on the colour you apply to it.

Let's take a more general look at the matrix to see how it affects the pixel colours:

```
Sr,  0,  0,  0, 0
 0, Sg,  0,  0, 0
 0,  0, Sb,  0, 0
 0,  0,  0, Sa, 0
Tr, Tg, Tb, Ta, 1
```

`S` stands for "scale" and `T` stands for translate. Your red component will be multiplied by `Sr` and then have `Tr` added to it, your green component will be multiplied by `Sg` and then have `Tg` added to it, your blue component will be multiplied by `Sb` and then have `Tb` added to it, and your alpha component will be multiplied by `Sa` and then have `Ta` added to it.

Therefore, to construct a matrix to colourise your image, you would do something like this:

```
Color colour = colourDialog.Color; // Or wherever you get your Color instance from
float[][] colourMatrixElements =
{
    new float[] { colour.R / 255.0f, 0, 0, 0, 0 },
    new float[] { 0, colour.G / 255.0f, 0, 0, 0 },
    new float[] { 0, 0, colour.B / 255.0f, 0, 0 },
    new float[] { 0, 0, 0, 1, 0 },
    new float[] { 0, 0, 0, 0, 1 }
};
var colourMatrix = new ColorMatrix(colorMatrixElements);
```

You can now use the `ColorMatrix` to colourise your image.

Comment: How to get reverse RGB matrix as given in the questions. 4x4